# Did Forrest's mom know about his love for Jenny?

Tags: plot-explanation, forrest-gump

In *Forrest Gump*, after Forrest goes to the stage where Jenny sings naked, Jenny once again walks away from Forrest's life. In the next scene, he is seen sad, sitting on the wood by the lakeside alone. His mom sees him, comes next to him and shows empathy that suggests she knows that his heart is broken because of Jenny. But she doesn't mention anything about it and instead tells him to be safe in Vietnam.

Did she know about Forrest's love for Jenny?

Comment: Moms ***always*** know.

Comment: More indirectly, does the fact that Forrest talks about his life (including inappropriate things) to **complete strangers** not imply that Forrest is open and honest? We see him continue that behavior for everyone he meets during the entire movie. Not only does that mean that his mother would know everything too; but since she is a single parent, she's probably the one who taught him that behavior in the first place.

Answer (score 8):

I believe **yes.** They're obviously close in the film and it seems reasonable to assume they discussed this. Whilst there's no direct evidence in the film to confirm this, Mrs. Gump is certainly aware of Forrest's love for her [in the novel](http://down02.putclub.com/virtual/backup/update/Download/Literature/%E3%80%8A%E9%98%BF%E7%94%98%E6%AD%A3%E4%BC%A0%E3%80%8B.pdf). From page 9:

> The problem was that wile Miss French was a nice kind lady, the things
> that she done to me that night was the kinds of things I'd have
> preferred to have done to me by Jenny Curran. An yet, there was no way
> I could see to even begin gettin that accomplished cause what with the
> way I am, it is not so easy to ask anyone for a date.
>
> That is to put
> it mildly. But on account of my new experience, I got up the courage
> to axe my mama what to do about Jenny, tho I certainly didn't say
> nothin bout me an Miss French. Mama said she'll take care of it for
> me, an she call up Jenny Curran's mama an splain the situation to her,
> an the nex evenin, lo an behole, who should appear at our door but
> Jenny Curran hersef!

Also on page 9:

> Mama said we can go to the movies an she give Jenny three dollars as
> we walk out of the house. Jenny ain't never been nicer, talkin an
> laughin an I am noddin an grinnin like a idiot.

So based on the fact in the books she was aware of his love, it seems likely she was in the film too.